# Get the data from a sql table into an ASP.NET GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, database-connection

I need to get my data from an sql table into an ASP.NET GridView. How can I do this? Should I use a xmlStr?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the .aspx file.
2. Go to the design mode.
3. From the control toolbox, add a GridView to the page.
4. Click on the newly added GridView.
5. Click the small '>' button that appear on the GridView.
6. From the choose data source drop down, select new datasource.
7. In the menu that appears, select SQL data source.
8. Add your DB connection and SELECT query to the data source.
9. Complete the wizard.
10. Press Yes when prompted to refresh the GridView fields.
11. Run the page, your GridView will be populated with the data from the SQL data source.